# Shorthand for many attr_reader in constructor

Tags: ruby

I find myself initializing a lot of variables in my classes and I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this. Once you get upwards of 20 variables it becomes a little redundant.

```
class Car
  attr_reader :make, 
    :model, 
    :year, 
    :id

  def initialize(args)
    @make = args["make"]
    @model = args["model"]
    @year = args["year"]
    @id = args["id"]
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you find yourself often creating 20 or so instance variables and you make them publicly available on top of that, there is something wrong with your design decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

```
class Car
  def initialize(args)
    args.each do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
    end
  end
end

car = Car.new({name: 'My car', make: 'BMW'})
p car #<Car:0x007fe80c8875d8 @name="My car", @make="BMW">
```

Comment: this only set an instance variable and raise an error when you try to read some of variables here.

Comment: I used a variation of this answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem called `immutable_struct`, if you care specifically about `attr_reader`
https://github.com/iconara/immutable_struct

```
class Spaceship < ImmutableStruct.new(:name, :max_speed)
end

ship = Spaceship.new('Enterprise', 'Warp 9')

puts ship.max_speed # => Warp 9

ship.max_speed = '299792458 m/s' # raises NoMethodError
```

But if you are fine with `attr_accessor`, ordinary `Struct` should do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some dynamic technique, to make you code flexible look example:

```
class Car
  def initialize(args = {})
    args.each do |ar|
      instance_variable_set(:"@#{ar.first}", ar.last)
    end
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &blk)
    if instance_variables.include? :"@#{m}"
      instance_variable_get("@#{m}")
    else
      super
    end
  end
end    
c = Car.new(foo: 1, bar: '132', baz: 'foo')    
puts c.foo
puts c.baz
puts c.bar    
puts c.barfoo
```

run in irb:

```
$ irb -r ./example.rb
#> 1
#> foo
#> 132
#> example.rb:14:in `method_missing': undefined method `barfoo' for #<Car:0x000000015bc740 @foo=1, @bar="132", @baz="foo"> (NoMethodError)
```

As you can see, you can pass as an argument a hash with any number of pair key-values as you want, but it's also raise an error when an attribute is not available

[`instance_variables`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_7_72/Object/instance_variables), [`instance_variable_set`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set), [`instance_variable_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get), [`method_missing`](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/method_missing)

Here's another trick with a [`class_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_eval) method:

```
class Car
  def initialize(args = {})
    args.each_pair do |k, v|
      self.class.class_eval do
        attr_reader k
      end
      instance_variable_set(:"@#{k}", v)
    end
  end
end
c = Car.new(foo: 1, bar: '132', baz: 'foo')
puts c.foo
puts c.baz
puts c.bar
puts c.inspect
```

run in irb:

```
#> 1
#> foo
#> 132
#> #<Car:0x00000002dc1fc0 @foo=1, @bar="132", @baz="foo">
```

Again in runtime add `attr_reader` for given key and set instance variable with a value of that key.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help myself from writing a gem to help with this, since I have often faced the same annoyance myself. It's called "attr_args_shorthand".

Basically you can do it like this with help from the gem:

```
class User
  def initialize(args)
    AttrArgsShorthand.set(self, args)
  end
end
```

And then you can do like this:

```
user = User.new(name: "Kasper")
user.name #=> "Kasper"
user.name = "Christina"
user.name #=> "Christina"
user.instance_variable_get(:@name) #=> "Christina"
```

https://github.com/kaspernj/attr_args_shorthand